# NameError: name 'lopp' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm getting an errror when i try to run my code.

```
  if b1==b2:
    for x in range(minc,maxc+1):
        if lopp [x][b1] != 'O':
                print("",end='')
                b1 = -10
                c1 = -10
                break
```

Comment: Please add the entire code. If this is the entire code, then where is `lopp` defined? How can python guess what `lopp` is if it was never declared?

Comment: Maybe `lopp` is a typo for `loop`?

Answer (score 1):

Please can you provide full code.

by this part of code I can just say that if you assign lopp like below

`lopp=['string1','string2','string3']`

there should not any error.